# Two pictures are there in single frame in chrome dev tools perf panel

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I tested the web page in chrome dev tool performance panel, there I found two images are there in the single frame interval. see the screenshot

In the screenshot , On a frame of 43ms, seeing two images in the frame.

[image]

what I understood is in single frame , single image of the page is sent to the display to render, but when I inspect in performance panel, seeing two image for the frame, could anyone help me in understanding why this two images are coming in single frame

Further in some frames images are in between frames in dev tool.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Screenshots are shown for each paint operation and those may happen asynchronously when a video or a picture is asynchronously decoded in GPU process. Try scrolling the chart all the way down and expand `Raster` or `GPU` rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing with chrome team member, found this is the bug in the performance panel of the dev tool see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=798755&q=frame&can=4

The issue is in the performance dev tools panel, **there is no relation between the frame and the screenshots**, that you can see in this simple example https://event-loop-tests.glitch.me/count-anim.html